# Monads being a mechanism for sequencing computations, is the below list still a monad though they are printed in a random order Scala

Tags: scala, monads, future, sequential, for-comprehension

```
for {
    i <- 1 to 5
  } yield Future(println(i))
```

Desugared to:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).map {i => Future(println(i))}
```

The above code prints numbers in **random order**.

Now, if we see the multiple definitions of Monad:
*a) Monad is a wrapper over an object*
*b) Monad is a mechanism for sequencing computations*

The question that I'm trying to answer is that shouldn't map operation on List monad wait for the first element in the list to be printed and only then go for the computation of the second element regardless of Future?

Sorry, it might be simple and I'm complicating it but it gets trickier for me to find simple reasoning. Answers will be much appreciated:)

Comment: Found another short article on if the Future is Monad, good to read. https://medium.com/@yuriigorbylov/is-future-a-monad-d7e4e07ddd82
What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare:

```
for {
  _ <- Future(println(1))
  _ <- Future(println(2))
  _ <- Future(println(3))
  _ <- Future(println(4))
  _ <- Future(println(5))
} yield ()
```

or

```
Future(println(1)).flatMap { _ =>
  Future(println(2))
}.flatMap { _ =>
  Future(println(3))
}.flatMap { _ =>
  Future(println(4))
}.flatMap { _ =>
  Future(println(5))
}
```

with

```
List(
  Future(println(1)),
  Future(println(2)),
  Future(println(3)),
  Future(println(4)),
  Future(println(5))
)
```

The first two create the next `Future` only after the former completed and made the result available. The last one creates all `Future`s at once (and it doesn't differ much in this regard from your example with `List[Future]`).

`Future` (as opposed to `IO` from Cats Effect, Monix's `Task` or ZIO) is eager, so it starts execution the moment you create it. For that reason you have sequential result in the first two examples, and random order (race condition) in the third example.

If you used `IO` instead of `Future` it would be more apparent because you wouldn't be able to just have `List[IO[Unit]]` and execute side effects - you would have to somehow combine the different IOs into one, and the way you would do it would make it obvious whether the effects will be sequential or parallel.

The bottom line is - whether or not `Future` is a monad depends on how the `.flatMap` behaves (and how it behaves with combination with `Future.successful`), so your results doesn't invalidate the claim that `Future` is a monad. (You can have some doubts if you start checking its behavior with exceptions, but that is another topic).

Answer (score 1):

The execution of map is sequential indeed, but when you wrap it to a Future it gets executed in an asynchronous manner, I mean it is evaluated in another thread and because of that, it is not possible to know what thread is going to finish earlier because it depends also in the thread management of the operating system and other considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your code snippets are still Monads in loose terms. When you did `.map()` on your object, the map picks element one by one in orderly fashion (from index 0 to index 4). And then it passes on that to an operation block (which is body of map - map is a higher order function that accepts a function of type f:This => That).

So monad operation's responsibility is picking it up and passing it as paramater to a function.

In your case the actual function type is:

```
f: Int => Future[Unit]
```

For clarity, your function actually looks like this:

```
def someFunction(i: Int): Future[Unit] = {
    Future {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

So, what the map operation did here is that it picked on item from your object (in sequence, one by one) and called the someFunction(i). And that's all a monad does.

Now to answer why your println are random, it's because of *JVM threads*.

If you re-define the body of you map like this

```
List(1,2,3,4,5)
  .map {i =>
    println(s"Going to invoke the println in another thread for $i")
    Future(println(i))
  }
```

You'll see that the first `println` will be in sequence - always! It proves that `.map()` picks your elements in sequence. While the next `println` may or may not be out of sequence. This out of order fashion is not because of monad operation `map` but because of multithreading nature in multi core CPUs.